# How to find if a specific meeting is new or has received updates?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I use Appointment.Bind() to checks whether a specific meeting is canceled or not. If it is not cancelled, how do i check if a meeting is new or has received an update?

I also don't see any property / flag that gets updated, when a meeting is new or has updates.

Awaiting any workaround / solution to this at earliest.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Sequence property from ICal http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/sequence.html. This is surfaced in EWS as AppointmentSequenceNumber https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.appointmentsequencenumber(v=exchg.80).aspx

Cheers
Glen